# How to verify ANY text is present with selenium IDE

Tags: text, selenium, ide, verify

I know how to verify if a specific text is present in a web page using Selenium IDE. But what I wanted to know is, can you verify that **any** text is present in an element?

For example there's a text box with the title "Top Champion". This text box will be changed daily with the name of a person. Now I just wanted to check whether there is a text in this text box, no matter what the text actually is. I've tried the verify text command and tried blanking the value, but it doesn't work. If the command can return a true or false command that would be really helpful

BTW, verify value doesn't work either since the element that I'm testing is not a form field

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet is as follows (I have written single tests for this for numbers)

Medium rigour:

```
waitForText | css=.SELECTORS | regex:.+?
```

This will wait until there is at least 1 character present.

Strong rigour (only works if you have a subset of characters present):

```
waitForText | css=.SELECTORS | regex:^[0-9]+$
```

This will wait until there is text. This text must start with a number, have at least 1 number, and then finish. It does not permit any character outside of the subset given. An example you could do to match numbersNAMEnumbers would be.

```
waitForText | css=.SELECTORS | regex:^[0-9]+[a-zA-Z]+[0-9]+$
```

This would wait for a string such as **253432234BobbySmith332**

Luke

Answer (score 0):

If i have understood your question properly there below is one way you can search for an element contains a string. Not sure if this is what you are looking.

```
List<WebElement> findElement = webElement.findElements(By.xpath("YOUR_TEXTINPUT_PATH_HERE"));
     if( findElement.size() > 0 ){
          if( findElement.get(0).getText() != null &&   findElement.get(0).getText().indexOf("THE_STRING_THAT_YOU_WANT_TO SEARCH") != -1 ) {
              // IF IT COMES HERE, THAT MEANS THE ELEMENT IS PRESENT WITH THE TEXT
          }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
store text|[your element]|StoredText  
execute script|return ${StoredText}.length > 0|x  
assert|x|true
```

Using these three lines in the Selenium IDE, the first line will extract the text from the element into the variable StoredText.
The second line will store whether the length of that text is greater than zero into the variable x (a true or false result).
The third line asserts that the result was true, failing the test if not.  You don't need the third line if all you want is the true or false result.

So if the element contains any text, the extracted text length will be greater than zero, the variable x will be true, and the assert will pass.  This verifies that any text is present in the element.

Comment: Please consider including a brief explanation of [how and why this solves the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/13138364). This will help future readers to better understand your solution. - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/30206045)